# How do I get the mythic horse?

Tags: red-dead-redemption

I need to get that horse! Some wikis said that the horse hade a fire mane and was hard to find but tell me the location of War, the horse.

Answer (score 8):

There are four mythic horses in "Undead Nightmare", rather than one. You asked about War specifically, but I'll include info on all four.

- [**War**](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/War_(horse)): Randomly spawns in New Austin.
- [**Famine**](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Famine): Randomly spawns in Mexico or Tall Trees.
- [**Pestilence**](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Pestilence_(horse)): Randomly spawns in West Elizabeth.
- [**Death**](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/Death): Randomly spawns anywhere the other three spawn, but only after you've tamed the other three horses.

When the horse spawns, you'll see a message that says something along the lines of "A mythical creature is nearby!". When you see that message, look around and get ready to tame the horse. None of them are incredibly difficult to tame.

Aside from having way more stamina than normal horses, each mythic horse has special abilites:

- War: Sets creatures on fire when it collides with them.
- Famine: Fastest horse, especially off-road.
- Pestilence: Resistant to damagea.
- Death: Resistant to damage. If it collides with an undead creature, it causes the creature's head to explode.

Comment: Sure thing. Don't forget to click the check on the left side of the answer to mark it as accepted!

Answer (score 0):

[It's DLC or included in the limited edition](http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/War_Horse).

Comment: [link]http://reddead.wikia.com/wiki/War_Horse[/link]